# Google Free Busy is not returning the events which are existing after 7:00 pm

Tags: google-calendar-api

Created an event in google calendar from 24th 06:00 pm to 25th 5:00 pm

[image]

When querying the Free Busy it's not returning actual slots

[image]

Some one suggest US how to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Seems like the issue here stems from the `timeMin` and `timeMax` parameters you have supplied for the request.**

The timezone of your calendar is `GMT-06:00` but `timeMin` and `timeMax` from the request are set for `GMT` hence the results you are receiving.

What you should do is to change the `timeMin` and `timeMax` to:

```
"timeMin": "2021-10-24T00:00:00-06:00",
"timeMax": "2021-10-25T23:29:00-06:00"
```

Please bear in mind that the `timezone` parameter is used to indicate the time zone used **in the response**.

#### Reference

- [Calendar API Freebusy:query](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/freebusy/query).

Comment: Thanks, it's my bad I missed to read the property USAGE